# Is there a server distro with the capability of syncing live data to multiple machines?

Tags: linux, centos, synchronization

Scenario: I have a main server that is used for pagebuilding/storing master data, and is accessed by a few clients on site. This company also has multiple branches with their own server that that connect to locally, but need to work with all the same data, and have it synchronized across all servers in real (or close) time. Is there a way/specific server OS that can sync live data across all of these servers? These servers would also need to be able to:

1. Configure AFP, FTP, CIFS, SMB
2. Continue to host their web server and database server in a Microsoft environment, but move the file server off to commodity hardware

Just wondering if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is something that Windows [dfs](/questions/tagged/dfs) can solve for you. I know you tagged this [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), but you also mention a Microsoft environment is available. Samba can be made to work with DFS if you still want a Linux environment for this role, but native Windows servers will be able to fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about (reasonably) static web pages. I can think of several ways to do file transfers, depending on your exact requirements and network environment. If you're really talking about database instances, my ideas would be different.

- If all of your servers can be fooled into thinking they're on the same LAN, consider setting up a shared NFS or GFS2 filesystem.
- If your servers are distant from each other and your synchronization doesn't need to be truly real-time, consider a cron job using [wget -r](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).
- I can also think of several command sequences that could be automated to work in near real-time.

Having suggested those, your questions also implies you're looking for an OS that keeps itself backed up in real time? Then, maybe you do an automatic restore to the other hosts? I'm not aware of any simple ways to do that.

Good luck!